# Parse raw text data and extract a particular value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, text

One of the columns in my database stores text information in the below mentioned format. The text is not in a standard format sometimes there might be additional text before "Insurance Date" field. When I do the split in Python it might place this "Insurance date" in different columns. I need to search for the value "Insurance date in all columns in this case.

Sample text

```
"Accumulation Period - period of time insured must incur eligible medical expenses at least equal to the deductible amount in order to establish a benefit period under a major medical expense or comprehensive medical expense policy.\n
Insurance Date 12/17/2018\n
Insurance Number 235845\n
Carrier Name SKGP\n
Coverage $240000"
```

Expected result

```
INS_NO     Insurance Date     Carrier Name
235845    12/17/2018          SKGP
```

How do we parse raw text information like this and extract the value of Insurance Date

I'm using the below logic to extract this but I'm don't know how to extract the date into another column

```
df= pd.read_sql(query, conn)
df2=df["NOTES"].str.split("\n", expand=True)
```

Comment: If it's always in this format, might be easier to use regular expressions.

Comment: _I'm don't know how to extract the date into another column_ Can you be more specific? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use regex

If the text follows a pattern (more or less), you could use `regex.`
See the python documentation for regular expressions operations [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

### Example

See and try with the code of two possible solutions [here](https://onlinegdb.com/ByAO9_bLL).
Below you can find a simplified example.

```py
text = """
Accumulation Period - period of time insured must incur eligible medical expenses at least equal to the deductible amount in order to establish a benefit period under a major medical expense or comprehensive medical expense policy.
Insurance Date 12/17/2018
Insurance Number 235845
Carrier Name SKGP
Coverage $240000
"""

pattern = re.compile(r"Insurance Date (.*)\nInsurance Number (.*)\nCarrier Name (.*)\n")

match = pattern.search(text)

print("Found:")
if match:
    for g in match.groups():
        print(g)
```

The output

```
Found:
12/17/2018
235845
SKGP
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this may get you close to what you need:

```
insurance = """
"Accumulation Period - period of time insured must incur eligible medical expenses at least equal to the deductible amount in order to establish a benefit period under a major medical expense or comprehensive medical expense policy.\n
Insurance Date 12/17/2018\n
Insurance Number 235845\n
Carrier Name SKGP\n
Coverage $240000"
"""

items = insurance.split('\n')
filtered_items = list(filter(lambda x: x != "", items))
del filtered_items[0]
del filtered_items[-1]
row = []
for item in filtered_items:
    row.append(item.split(' ')[-1])

columns = ["INS_NO ", "Insurance Date", "Carrier Name"]      
df = pd.DataFrame([row],columns=columns)
df
```

Output:

```
    INS_NO  Insurance Date  Carrier Name
0   12/17/2018  235845     SKGP
```